# UICollectionView offset paging by item size

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, layout, uicollectionview

I'v created the following layout using UITableView and UICollectionView as the reusable cell, my Item size is configured to half of the collectionView at run time at `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method.

Result:

[image]

How can I make the paging scroll offset, to be the content of one item, so the swiping result would be:

[image]